# Calculation of translation speed of a tropical cyclone from output data from models?

Tags: tropical-cyclone

What is the translation speed of a tropical cyclone and how can it be calculated from model outputs? I have mean sea level pressure, u-wind and v-wind.

I understand that it is the linear speed at which tropical cyclone moves forward.

Comment: What do you mean how to compute it? Plus you state that you know the answer of the main question...

Comment: If you want to *compute* it, are you talking about modeling?

Comment: @JanDoggen : I mean how to calculate it.

Comment: The updated text helps us much better understand what you are trying to do :)